# Bit manipulation; Converting a 16-bit value into an array of 16 Boolean values? C language

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am reading over some code and I finally need to figure out how this function works. I understand what it is used for and why it is used, but further than that, its magic.

From what I understand the function takes in a value that had all the info compressed into it. So instead of having 16 integers that only hold the value 0 or 1, it packs each 0 or 1 value into the bits of the integer. And this function takes those bits out and puts them each into a char.

The function is called like so

```
DecompressInputs(DigOut[0], &input[64]);
```

With DigOut and input being an arrays defined as such

```
UWORD DigOut[2];
char input[NUM_INPUTS]; // NUM_INPUTS = 80
```

And the function itself

```
/*===============================================*/
/* Name: DecompressInputs                        */
/* Purpose: Convert a 16 bit value into an array */
/*  of 16 boolean values.                        */
/*===============================================*/
static __inline__ void DecompressInputs(int bits,char *input)
{
    char i = 16;
    while(i)
    {
        if(bits & 0x0001)
            *input++ = 0x0a5;
        else
            *input++ = 0x000;

        bits = bits >> 1;   
        i-=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you're representing the on bits with 0xA5, but the rest is pretty straightforward: just loop 16 times, mask off the low bit and shift the value right to move the next bit into place. It's also pretty bad form that the function's output is named "input". :-)

Comment: Yeah all of the code I work with has bad form. So the 0x0A5 is as alien to you as it is to me? That's mostly where I was caught up, I just didn't understand why it was that and still don't. ---- And i=16 in the function because UWORD is 16 bits long; obvious..?

Comment: `bits = bits >> 1` -> `bits =>> 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so lets try to explain what's going on here.

First thing first, I believe that `static __inline__ void DecompressInputs(int bits,char *input)` should be updated to `static __inline__ void DecompressInputs(int bits,char *output)` because it looks more like an output value than an input one: however, this is detail.

Lets try to make it a bit clearer:

```
static __inline__ void DecompressInputs(int bits,char *output)
{
    char i = 16;
    while(i)
    {
        /* This will be true if the lowest bit of bits is 1. Otherwise, this is false */
        if(bits & 0x0001)
        {
         /* For whatever reason, you chose 0x0a5 to represent a bit whose value is 1. We write that value to the char pointed by output */
            *output = 0x0a5;
         /* Now that the value has been written, increment output so the next write will go the next char */
            output++;
        }
        else
        {
          /* Same here, but we store 0x00 instead */
            *output = 0x000;
            output++;
        }

        // Now we bitshift bits, so the next time we do bits & 0x0001, we will check for the second bit of the original integer
        bits = bits >> 1;   
        i-=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `0x0a5` and `0x000` parts somehow suggest me that `char` is 12-bits long on OP's platform... Not sure if that is the case. (And if it isn't, I can't possibly understand why OP is appending an extra 0. Whatever...)

Answer (score 0):

The function checks for the LSB in `bits` (`if(bits & 0x0001)`). If that bit is set, the first char in `input` is set to `'\xa5'` (whatever character that might be), otherwise to `'\0`. Then `input` is incemented, so that in the next loop the second char of the original array will be set and `bits` is shifted (`bits = bits >> 1;`) so the next loop will check for the 2nd LSB of the original value. That is performed 16 times to decompress 16 bits.

Let's have an example:

bits = 0x0005 (binary 0000 0000 0000 0101)

then we have

1. `bits & 0x0001` is true ==> input[0] = '\xa5'

   `bits = bits >> 1` ==> bits = 0x0002 ( binary ... 0010)
2. `bits & 0x0001` is false ==> input[1] = '\x00' (regarding the **original** input)

   `bits = bits >> 1` ==> bits = 0x0001 ( binary ... 0001)
3. `bits & 0x0001` is true ==> input[2] = '\xa5'

   `bits = bits >> 1` ==> bits = 0x0000 ( binary ... 0000)

.. and so on

Comment: 0xA5 is the "Yen" symbol. No idea what it's doing there.

Answer (score 0):

This version of the code might be a little easier to understand because it doesn't rely on modifying values as much:

```
static __inline__ void DecompressInputs(int bits, char *output)
{
    for (int bit = 0; bit < 16; ++bit)
    {
        int mask = 1 << bit;
        if (bits & mask)
            output[bit] = 0x0a5;
        else
            output[bit] = 0;
    }
}
```